# Orientation of 3 points $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ in logarithmic scale

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry

Is there a fast way (without evaluating $e^x$) to calculate orientation of 3 ordered points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ in logarithmic scale?

In other words we need to calculate sign of the following determinant:
\begin{vmatrix}
 1&  e^{a_x}&e^{a_y} \\ 
 1&  e^{b_x}&e^{b_y} \\ 
 1&  e^{c_x}&e^{c_y} 
\end{vmatrix}